# matplotlib.candlestick2_ohlc weird unequal bar width and line position

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

Here is what I got:
[image]

Basically just with

```
candlestick2_ohlc(ax, df.open, df.high, df.low, df.close,
                  colorup='r', colordown='c', width=0.4)
```

I only changed the line color in `candlestick2_ohlc` function to `colorup` if Open<=Close and `colordown` if Open > Close.

Did you notice that the bar width are not the same? And line positions in each bar are not at the center, and the line segment inside the bar's body are not in line with the line segments outside the bar's body.

Let me zoom in:

[image]

Anyone knows why this is happening? How to address this?

Comment: This is probably a problem with resolution. Coordinates in plots have to be projected to a pixel number when being exported. This will inevitably lead to rounding errors. You might get better results exporting to a vector format like pdf or by increasing the dpi of the figure.

Comment: I tried `fig=plt.gcf(); fig.get_dpi();` The default dpi is 100, now I tried to increase the dpi to 300 by `fig.set_dpi(300)`， indeed it gets better but I can't see the whole plot, it's like a zoomed in plot, I can only see the upper left corner of the original plot.

Comment: **Where** do you see that plot? Which program are you using?